# Is it possible to use Docker in PyCharm CE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pycharm

I have to debug python project. PyCharm IDE seems good (I downloaded Community Edition, because it's free).

But main script is "called" from Docker (I am not quite familiar with it). All sources I've found say that Docker can be added as Remote Interpreter.
[image]

PyCharm CE has [limitations](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), so it's not possible to add "Remote Interpreter" in this IDE.

Do you know some workarounds?
Maybe PyCharm could be connected to "something" (some unofficial project), and "something" uses Docker?
 
Or maybe there is another good IDE with such possibilities? (I wouldn't like to debug in command line).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not that it has limitations. It's only that the docker version and connection through ssh require the professional version and thus payment.

Comment: Any particualr reason why you have to debug a script running inside docker? Why not debug outside?

Comment: @DroidX86 As far as I remember, the python process was started in Docker, and it depended on other processes started in Docker, and I wasn't able to start them manually.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to have an instance of PyCharm CE running from inside the Docker project itself:
https://benjamintan.io/blog/2019/09/22/using-pycharm-ce-in-docker-for-great-good/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)